# Is the system firing an event when a process is started?

Tags: android, events, process

I want to ask if Android is firing an event when a process has been started? Or is there any proper way to find out if a process has been started?

I have implemented some basic algorithm of catching when a process of interest has been started but it's working in a service with 5 mins checking if the process is running or not.

My task is finding out when an application is started and stopped and count the time it has been active.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know is a app started or not, use [ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) is enough.

If you need a real-time reporting of a started process, the answer is no, and it is not possible using the current sdk.

You can take some [existing approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172092/1365960) on a rooted device.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. So the only way to find out when a process is running is the way I described above and already implemented? Having a service who checks on a fixed period of time if the process is in the running processes list.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by checking the processes list or call ActivityManagers for this list continually.

Comment: If I do this checks on every 5 mins, for example. How much is it gonna drain the battery? I mean, is it a high power consuming operation or it's not gonna affect the battery so much?

Comment: I think 5 mins is ok, some email app check mails every 5 mins. @Seishin And I've updated the answer to add a non-real-time solution.

Comment: @JermaineXu, I'm doing it this way. Every 5 mins I call ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses and checks if the process of interest is within it. If it's - increment the running time with 5 mins, if not - do nothing. But this way it's not that accurate because the app could have been started or stopped sometime between these 5 mins. 
But I highly appreciate your answers.

Comment: Yes, exactly, so I said it is almost impossible to get what you want on Android unless you are working on a rooted device, or you can modify the firmware. @Seishin