# Listening for new PIDs and PIDs that are closed

Tags: linux, process, pid

I'm creating a monitor that will detect when new processes (PIDs) are created and when PIDs are closed. How would I go about doing this?

What I found thus far would be to wait for directory changes in /proc, using the `inotify` functions. Is this the only way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux: detect launching of programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075013/linux-detect-launching-of-programs)

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8255487/103167), not the accepted zero-vote one.