# Listening for new Processes in Linux Kernel Module

Tags: linux, process, kernel-module

Is it possible to get notified (via callback or similar) when a new process is executed, when one is closed, and when state changes (ie. stopped, paged, etc)? In user-land, it would be easy to set up a directory listener on /proc.

Comment: "In user-land, it would be easy to set up a directory listener on /proc." Actually, no, that doesn't work. But [the /proc connector does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075013/linux-detect-launching-of-programs).

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered kprobes? You can use kprobes to execute a callback function when some kernel code is executed. E.g., you could add a `do_fork` kprobe to alert when new processes are created as in [this example](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/samples/kprobes/kprobe_example.c).

Similarly, you can add a probe for `do_exit()` to catch when processes exit.

For changing state, you could have have a return probe on `sched_switch()` and catch when the state changes. Depending on your application, this may add too much overhead.

If you only wish to collect data, perform some light processing, and aren't looking to do much more with the kernel module, systemtap may be a good alternative to writing a kernel module: https://sourceware.org/systemtap/documentation.html

More details on kprobes:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt

`sched_switch()` systemtap example:
https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/profiling/sched_switch.stp