# How to get notified when a process ends under linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, operating-system

How do I monitor a number of processes and if one process ends, I would like to run some code.

I have found several examples which used polling to achieve this but I am looking for a method to get pushed (probably by the OS) when a process dies. Is this possible with C or C++? It should run on any modern Linux.

If there is any chance, I would like to do that without needing root privileges.

EDIT:

The job of this whole program is to monitor these processes and send this information to another server where it gets integrated into a website.

I have not started these processes but I could ensure that they are started as the same user.

I thought it should be possible because the top / ps command under Linux also gives you information about processes you haven't started.

Comment: The question should be "is this possible with Linux". The C part won't be a problem then.

Comment: About root: Are you okay with getting notified only about your users processes? (I don't even know if such a notification is possible at all, but if it is, I'm sure only root can do it for *all* processes)

Comment: Do you have the pids of the processes to watch? Or how do you identify the set of processes to watch?

Comment: I doubt anyone uses polling to find whether a process has terminated. `wait()` or `sigaction() /w SIGCHLD`.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28602298/3134621

Comment: @EOF This can only be performed for childprocesses, not in general

Comment: @Ctx: Then the monitored processes should be spawned by the monitoring process. That doesn't seem particularly onerous.

Comment: @EOF please don't single-handedly change the premises of the question, this might not be possible

Comment: You might want to let us know in broader terms what it is that you are trying to do and add more details about your environment. E.g. are you trying to build a process monitor? Can you control how that process is launched? Do you have access to its source code? What are your performance/latency requirements?

Comment: @OP: *Did* you start these processes from within this one? The answer changes completely depending on whether you did or didn't.

Comment: I added some information

Comment: What exactly are the monitored processes? How and by whom are they started? Could you slightly change their program (or wrap it in some C program of yours)? Please improve your question

Comment: I am not sure how much control you have over the environment that is calling the processes, but if you can get the process you are interested in to inherit the write end of a pipe, you can do a blocking read on the read end of the pipe and it shouldn't return until all the write-ends are closed.

Answer (score 8):

In general on Linux you can't be notified (with [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) or `SIGCHLD` -see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)- ...) about non-child processes, or processes outside of your process group or session.

And on some Linux your (non-root) process might not even be allowed to query the existence of other processes.

Of course, there is `/proc/` (having one numerical-named directory per process, e.g. `/proc/1234/` for process of pid 1234, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) that you might regularly scan (e.g. with [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)...) but you cannot be notified (see [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), which does *not work* for pseudo-file systems like `/proc/` ...) about changes inside it. Notice that `/proc/` is a pseudo file system, and accessing it does not involve any disk IO so is quite quick.

So what you could do is scan `/proc/` every few seconds using  [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), `readdir`, [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html), [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) in a loop. BTW, that in theory is not fail-proof (in principle, not in practice, the kernel might reuse the same pid within a few seconds), and probably won't catch all *short-living* processes (such as `ls` shell commands).

Such a periodic scan of `/proc` is very probably what the [top(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) utility is doing. You could check that by diving into the source code of `top` or by [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)-ing it.

If your C code knows already the pid of some process and simply wants to check the existence of that process, it can use [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) with a signal number 0.

See also [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) & [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

If you can change the code of the monitored programs or replace them (e.g. by your small C program wrapping them) things are very different; e.g. you could replace `/usr/bin/foo` with `/usr/local/bin/foo-wrapper` and code a `foo-wrapper.c` which `fork`-s & `exec`-s the original `/usr/bin/foo` then [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) on it and finally [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) or [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) some message on some [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) or [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), and use a [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) based [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) in your monitor. If you can get all the programs `fork`-ed by your monitor things are also different (use `waitpid`...). See my [execicar.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/execicar.c) program for inspiration.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure `auditd` daemon to create audit records (log lines) when a process ends. And then monitor `auditd` log file with `inotify`.

Provided you have access to `auditd` configuration and its log file.

Answer (score -3):

note that the /proc/ directory holds a directory for each running process' PID
for example /proc/1 is PID 1

under that directory there's the cmdline file which can be used to determine the PID's command, i.e:
cat /proc/1/cmdline 
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd

you can traverse the /proc/[09]*   irectories looking for a cmdline that matches what you are looking for, when you match that command you can simply check if the cmdline still matches the original one(the same PID can be used for another process if it had terminated

here's a simple piece of code that gets that job done:
I haven't written most of the error correction(program crashes if the application isn't found, some other errors that cause segfault)
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2){
    printf("usage:\nproc <processname>\n");
    return 2;
  }
  char * processName = argv[1];
  int pid = 0;
  FILE *processFile;
  char *monitoredProcess;
  DIR *root;
  struct dirent *dir;
  root = opendir("/proc/");
if (root)
  {
    int reading = 0;
    while((dir=readdir(root))!=NULL && reading==0)
    {
     // printf("dir name:%i\n",dir->d_ino);
      if (dir->d_name[0] > 47 && dir->d_name[0] < 58) {
    char directory[128];
    strcpy(directory,"/proc/");
        strcat(directory,dir->d_name);
    strcat(directory,"/cmdline");
    processFile = fopen(directory,"r");
    if (processFile == NULL) {
      printf("Error");
      return 1;
    }
    char line[2048];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, processFile) != NULL) {
      if(strstr(line,processName)) {
        printf("%s\n",directory);
        monitoredProcess = directory;
        reading = 1;
      }
      //the pid has been determined at this point, now to monitor
    }
      }
    }
    //monitoring
    printf("monitoring %s\n",monitoredProcess);
    while(processFile=fopen(monitoredProcess,"r")) {
      char line[2048];
      while (fgets(line, sizeof line, processFile) != NULL) {
    if(strstr(line,processName) == NULL)
      printf("application terminated\n");
      }
      sleep(3);
      fclose(processFile);
    }
  } else
    printf("unable to open folder\n");
}
```

Comment: This is polling, which the OP already states having code for. The question is if *notification* is possible.