# Is it possible to find out that a certain process has started in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, process

In my C++ program, I need to know when a logged-in user has started a process in Linux. Is it possible to somehow add a hook like in Windows OS so that I can receive a notification that the user has launched such and such a program? It is also important for me to know that the process has completed.
where can I read about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`inotify`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) and/or Linux auditing.

For `inotify`:

> The inotify API provides a mechanism for monitoring filesystem
> events.  Inotify can be used to monitor individual files, or to
> monitor directories. ...

You can use [`inotify_add_watch()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html) to add `IN_OPEN`, `IN_ACCESS`, and maybe one or both `IN_CLOSE_*` event watches.

Once the executable for the process is opened and accessed, you can find the process ID [using `lsof`-type searches through `/proc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583563/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-list-of-open-file-descriptors-for-a-given-pid) (no, there's no standard Linux library that I'm aware of that provides `lsof`-type functionality via a callable API).

Once you have the PID, you can't put an `IN_DELETE_SELF` watch on the `/proc/PID` directory to know when the process ends as `inotify` does not support pseudo-filesystems such a `/proc` per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90627/notify-of-changes-on-a-file-under-proc) question and its answer (and many others...), but there are many other ways to know.  See [**How to get notified when a process ends under linux?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800568/how-to-get-notified-when-a-process-ends-under-linux).

There is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34808583/4756299) to that question:

> You can configure `auditd` daemon to create audit records (log lines) when a process ends. And then monitor `auditd` log file with `inotify`.
>
> Provided you have access to `auditd` configuration and its log file.

Although if you configure `auditd` to audit things like file opens and process start and end, you probably won't need to nor want to put an `inotify` watch on the audit log file.

And if you use `auditd` to watch for a process ending, you can also use it to watch for the process starting and omit using `inotify` entirely.  That would also allow you to skip recreating `lsof` functionality in your code to find the PID as the PID will be in the audit data.

Comment: thank you answer! Could you explain in more detail how I can use auditing to monitor running processes? How can I use it to find out that such and such a user process has started?
Should I create a specific service that will be launched when the user session starts and monitor the applications he launches? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @urivskay Configuring Linux auditing can be complex.  Red Hat provides a good guide for getting started: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-linux-auditing-auditd