# list of all executions in Linux

Tags: linux, program-flow

Is it possible to find out all the programs getting executed in Linux. There will be many scripts and other executables getting launched and killed during the life time of a system and I would like to get a list of these (or a print while execuction start). I am looking for this to understand program flow in an embedded board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a kernel interface which will notify a client program of every fork, exec, and exit.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255487/5844347

Answer (score 1):

Type `ps aux` in the terminal will give information about the processes(Started time, runtime), [more information](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/) about keep track of processes

Comment: That only displays information on processes that are currently running.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `ps -e` and eventually `crontab` if you want to take that information periodically.