# How to change Linux kernel configuration in docker image?

Tags: linux, docker, kernel, alpine-linux, netlink

I'm trying to catch processes' `fork()` and `exec()` event details for some security purposes. And then I found this question: [How to detect the launching of programs on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075013/how-to-detect-the-launching-of-programs-on-linux)

I built a [monitor program](https://github.com/konstantin89/linux-netlink-process-monitoring) in docker container with image `alpine`, and run it successfully. But there is no any data output in `stdout` of console. So I suspect that kernel doesn't send processes' events by netlink, how to check if `CONFIG_CONNECTOR` and `CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS` are enabled? And if not, how can I enable it in some ways?

Comment: Are you trying to see `fork()` and `exec()` calls that happen on the host or in the container?

Comment: A Docker container shares its host's kernel.  If you need a different kernel, you need to run your application inside a full virtual machine.

Comment: @HansKilian I tried execute some commands and there is no any information output.

Comment: @DavidMaze I think you are right, I found another answer said that need to use `host` network in docker, but there is not what I expected.